# Problem in running .net framework 4.0 website on iis 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, cgi, isapi

Hey I got problem in running `.NET framework 4.0` website on `IIS7.0`.
the error I got is like:

**HTTP Error 404.2** - Not Found "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the `ISAPI` and `CGI` Restriction list settings on the Web server".

```
Module : IsapiModule , 
Notification : ExecuteRequestHandler, 
Handler : PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit , 
Error Code : 0x800704ec
```

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Go to IIS manager and click on the server name.  Then click on the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" icon under the IIS header.  Change ASP.NET 4.0 from "Not Allowed" to "Allowed".

Comment: emphasize: click on SERVER NAME not SITE NAME to find the option

Comment: actually, I don't even have the CGI option. I am using windows 7, 64 bit. Trying to get ssrs to work.

Comment: make sure you start IIS as Administrator :)

Comment: For at least today, you are my favorite person. This fixed a problem I've Been chasing for several hours. Great answer.

Comment: @Steam be sure to click on Server name and not Site name as suggested by MacGyver

Comment: you are going to heaven!

Answer (score 8):

If you look in the **ISAPI And CGI Restrictions**, and everything is already set to **Allowed**, then make sure that the **ASP.NET v4.0.30319** handlers are even in the list. In my case they were not. This can be easy to overlook.

---

I added one for 32 `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll` and another for 64 bit `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll`. You can name them both the same `ASP.NET v4.0.30319`.

Check **Allow extension path to execute**.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to the IIS Manager.
2. open the server name like `(PC-Name)\`.
3. then double click on the ISAPI and CGI Restriction.
4. then select ASP.NET v4.0.30319(32-bit) Restriction allowed.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was more severe: turns out asp.net was not correctly registered.

[This response worked fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10541165/315376).

> simply ran the following command at the command prompt
>
> ```
> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
> ```
>
> If I had been on a 32 bit system, it would have looked like the following:
>
> ```
> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Open IIS and click the server name
Step 2. Double click “ISAPI and CGI Restrictions”
Step 3. Right click ASP.NET v4.0.30319 and select “allow”

After 
Stopping and Starting the World Wide Web Publishing Service

1.Go to Start > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Services.
2.In the services list, right-click World Wide Web Publishing Service, and then   click Stop (to stop the service), Start (to start it after it has been stopped), or Restart (to restart the service when it is running).

Pramesh

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Delphi, or other native compiled CGI, this solution will work:

1. As other pointed, go to IIS manager and click on the server name. Then click on the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" icon under the IIS header.
2. If you have everything allowed, it will still not work. You need to click on "Edit Feature Settings" in Actions (on the right side), and check "Allow unspecified CGI modules", or "Allow unspecified ISAPI modules" respectively.
3. Click OK

Comment: Was beating my head for a few days and had to do this "Edit Feature Settings" to get a company Single Sign-On plugin to work in Classic mode

Answer (score 1):

In our case the solution to this problem did not involve the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" settings. The error started occuring after operations staff had upgraded the server to .NET 4.5 by accident, then downgraded to .NET 4.0 again. This caused some of the IIS websites to forget their respective correct application pools, and it caused some of the application pools to switch from .NET Framework 4.0 to 2.0. Changing these settings back fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the **ISAPI And CGI Restrictions**, and everything is already set to Allowed, and the ASP.NET installed is **v4.0.30319**, then in the right, at the "**Actions**" panel click in the "**Edit Feature Settings...**" and check both boxes. In my case, they were not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the AppPool Manged Pipeline Mode from "Integration" to "Classic".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of application, another thing to check is under the Advanced Settings for the Application Pool make sure "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to True.

I'd checked everything in this thread when I had this issue but all had already been setup correctly, I found this was the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't have ISAPI and CGI Restrictions option listed, here is how to add it. [How to add ISAPI and CGI Restrictions](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/isapicgirestriction)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After mapping of Application follow these steps

Open IIS 
Click on Applications Pools
Double click on website
Change Manage pipeline mode to "classic"
click Ok.

Ow change .Net Framework Version to Lower version

Then click Ok