# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found -The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: .net, iis-7, migration

We are migrating our web application which is built on 1.1 Framework to 4.0 Framework. The older server was a Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 and the newer one is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1.

Coming to Pipeline Mode, I tried both Integrated as well as Classic, neither helped. I had a httphandler on my IIS 5 on older server to handle any file extension of type ".controller". To get the same effect, I added a Managed handler as well as a ".controller" to Request Filtering and set it to "Allow" state.

Error Details:

Server Error in Application "mywebsite.com"Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed Error Information
Module IIS Web Core
Notification MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x80070002

Requested URL http://www.MYWEBSITE.com:80/MyProject/
Physical Path C:\Projects\Folder\MyProjectSolution\MyProject\Abc.controller
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous

Most likely causes:
•The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
•The URL contains a typographical error.
•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
•Create the content on the Web server.
•Review the browser URL.
•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Nothing helps :(. Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks,
Nadeem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in running .net framework 4.0 website on iis 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578134/problem-in-running-net-framework-4-0-website-on-iis-7-0)

Comment: I am facing same problem. Can you please share it how could u solve it ?