# How do I set ISAPI/CGI option in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: exception, iis, iis-7, cgi, isapi

This article explains how to correct an exception that's often seen when switching an ASP.NET application to .NET 4.0.  However, I don't have this option in IIS when using Windows 7 Home Premium.  Does this mean the option isn't there at all, or is it just not visible?  If it doesn't exist in the GUI, is this being set in the Windows Registry somewhere?  I want to be able to correct this exception without upgrading Windows.  Is this even possible?

Issue:

[Problem in running .net framework 4.0 website on iis 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578134/problem-in-running-net-framework-4-0-website-on-iis-7-0)

Fix (see Windows 7):

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/isapiCgiRestriction

... see this screen shot (in Fix page)

http://i1.iis.net/resources/images/configreference/isapiCgiRestriction_howto_63.png?cdn_id=20120424-001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to click on the server name in the tree hierarchy, not the site name.  Then the option appeared.