# How to get rid of this error Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net, iis

Using IIS7.5, the website works fine in Visual Studio but when I try to deploy on IIS get the following error.

> Module IIS Web Core
>   Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated
>   Error Code 0x8007000d
>   Requested URL http://localhost:80/EFT/default.aspx
>   Physical Path
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EFT_Converter\default.aspx
>   Logon Method
>   Anonymous
>   Logon User

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip on first glance; certainly other users might also find that post useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your handlers are defined in the web.config, add a *<clear />* before the first item in the list, if there is not one there already. Also make sure that the application pool running the web site is running the version of .Net that you are targeting in your code.

Comment: I actually have no handlers specified in my web.config, and .net version is correct in web.config

Comment: In IIS, is your application pool set to .Net 2.0 or 4.0? That should match what is in your web.config also. The version of .Net the application pool uses is set in IIS, and not in your web.config.

Comment: It is set to 4 in IIS which matches what it says in my web.config

Answer (score 20):

The version of .Net you are using has not been registered with IIS correctly.
If it is .Net version 4 on a 64-bit 2008 server use these two commands to fix it.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: ..also worth checking that the application pool is set to the right framework and that iis application actually points to your folder

Answer (score 6):

Open command prompt  on window and run:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set web config in this way:

```
<system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Ensure you have ASP.NET has been installed correctly. You should see default application pool named "ASP.NET 4" or something like this. If it's not looks like ASP.NET not installed correctly. Try aspnet_regiis -i in .NET 4 CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7) post.

From the post:

1. Click Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Run
   In the Open textbox paste in the following line (see list of all .NET Framework version install, repair and unistall command lines here):

For silent repair on 32 bit computer with .Net Framework version 4.0.30319 use:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client\setup.exe /repair /x86 /x64 /ia64 /parameterfolder Client /q /norestart
```

For silent repair on 64 bit computer with .Net Framework version 4.0.30319 use:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client\setup.exe /repair /x86 /x64 /ia64 /parameterfolder Client /q /norestart
```

2. Click OK to start the repair. 
 3. After, the repair ran for a few minutes, I restarted IIS 7.5, and things began to work correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that removing the following folder helped, even with the non-Express edition.Express:

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\IISExpress`