# 405 Method Not Allowed for PUT and DELETE in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have built some API endpoints using ASP.NET Web API. When i tried to do **PUT** or **DELETE** request, got **405 Method Not Allowed**  error. But it is working fine for **GET** and **POST** request.

Interestingly, PUT and DELETE is working nicely when i have hosted the project in local IIS. It's only throwing **405** error in the **DEV** server.

In my **web.config**:

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

What am i missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does adding this `<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>`  inside `<modules>`  and `<remove name="WebDAV" />` inside `<handlers>` help?

Comment: Yes it fixed my problem. Can you please elaborate the answer? Thanks

Comment: You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346907/how-to-remove-webdav-module-from-iis/65647298#65647298)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 or later to develop a Web API application, IIS Express is the default web server. This web server is a scaled-down version of the full IIS functionality that ships in a server product, and this web server contains a few changes that were added for development scenarios. For example, the WebDAV module is often installed on a production web server that is running the full version of IIS, although it may not be in actual use.

The development version of IIS, (IIS Express), installs the WebDAV module, **but the entries for the WebDAV module are intentionally commented out, so the WebDAV module is never loaded on IIS Express**. As a result, your web application may work correctly on your local computer, but you may encounter HTTP 405 errors when you publish your Web API application to your production web server.

Since your DEV server has full IIS functionality (with WebDAV) it will register multiple handlers for the same verb/method and one of the handlers is blocking the expected handler from processing the request.

So, the WebDAV is overriding your HTTP PUT and DELETE. During the processing of an HTTP PUT request, IIS calls the WebDAV module, When the WebDAV module is called, it checks its configuration and sees it is disabled, so it will return HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error for any request that resembles a WebDAV request.

You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

To disable WebDAV add the following into your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
 </modules>
 <handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Saved my day. This is one of the most weird web server errors that ever occured to me. It started out of the nowhere. Maybe there was an update with an breaking change for IIS the last months?

Answer (score 0):

[**Hasta Tamang**s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970976/4751920) answer was perfect for solving the problem for one application, but we got multiple on the server, so we identified the core problem.

We still don't know how the problem appeared in the first place as the apis were running without any problem for years. Fortunately this has only happened on the Development system, maybe it was due to an IISExpress update where someone just checked all of the defaults? No idea ...

But you can just uninstall the webdav module on the whole server from the Server Manager.

[image: Screenshot of the server manager with the feature location]

Interestingly this is even totally disabled on our PROD server, but not on INT.

Unchecking and uninstalling the `WebDAV Publishing` and restarting the server solved our problem :-)

[Docs about uninstalling modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules#to-install-iis-and-aspnet-modules-on-windows-server-2012-using-the-ui)