# How to fix 405 method not allowed?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've been trying find a solution about 405 method not allowed problem. There is an api for login and register. Register post method works fine but when i send credentials from postman i get 405 error. I've searched solution and  `<remove name="WebDAVModule" />` is very widely answer but it doesn't solve my problem. How can i fix it ?

CreateUser works fine.

```
   [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody]RegisterVm register)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<User>(register);
            var result = await _userBusiness.CreateUser(userIdentity, register.Password).ConfigureAwait(true);
            if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

            return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
        }
```

Login doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginVm login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(login.Email, login.Password);
        if (identity == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));
        }

        var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, _jwtFactory, login.Email, _jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }).ConfigureAwait(true);
        return new OkObjectResult(jwt);
    }
```

Comment: You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346907/how-to-remove-webdav-module-from-iis/65647298#65647298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, only two reasons for this:

1. The user agent is accidentally sending an incorrect HTTP method.
2. The server is expecting only a handful of valid HTTP methods for the requested resource which don't include what you need.

Since 2 is obviously not the answer, you need to make sure that your caller is actually `POSTING` data, instead of using GET, PUT, DELETE or any other verb.

Microsoft documentation for debugging and resolving this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications