# ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 and Integrated managed pipeline mode error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

In `VS2013` project settings I changed my `ASP.NET Web API` application to run in `IIS` from `IIS EXPRESS` on the same computer.  It worked in `IIS Express` but I can't get it to run in `IIS` without this error about `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` and
`An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.`

I have tried everything in the posts below but nothing works to stop this error except changing the app pool to from `Integrated` to `Classic`.  That option doesn't work either because brings more errors.

[An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p)

[WebDAV and WebAPI together cause Error: Handler “ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0” has a bad module “ManagedPipelineHandler” in its module list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156397/webdav-and-webapi-together-cause-error-handler-extensionlessurlhandler-integra?lq=1)

[An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p?rq=1)

[Handler “ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0” has a bad module “ManagedPipelineHandler” in its module list](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2013/01/handler-extensionlessurlhandler.html)

I'm using `VS 2013`, `ASP.NET 4.5.1`, `IIS 7.5`, and it's running on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard`

This is my `web.config` `system.web` and `webserver` sections

```
<system.web>    
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />  
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This is the error returned

```
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"
Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary 
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error

An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in 
Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Detailed Error Information 
ModuleConfigurationValidationModule NotificationBeginRequest HandlerExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 
Error Code0x80070032 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/Token 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Token 
Logon Method Not yet determined 
Logon User Not yet determined 
Failed Request 

Tracing Log Directory C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles 
Most likely causes: system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Things you can try: If the application supports it, disable client impersonation.
If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error, it can 
be disabled by setting system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false.

Move this application to an application pool using Classic .NET mode 
- for example, %SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app "Default Web Site/" /applicationPool:"Classic .NET AppPool"

(You can set "Classic .NET AppPool" to the name of another application pool running in Classic managed pipeline mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

The information in the links in my question worked.  Specifically

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

this

```
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

and this

```
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I also opened the `Configuration Editor` in IIS for the site and changed the `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration`  and `runManagedModulesForWebDAVRequests` to `false`

There was something else going on that was keeping me from knowing this was working.  I am using [ASP.NET Web API membership to authenticate using individual accounts](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) and when I call the `/Token` to login it was going to root website and my application was in a virtual directory.  When that call was made it was raising the `Integrated managed pipeline mode error`.  I created a new site in IIS for the application instead of using a virtual directory.  There might be a way get it to work while using the virtual directory but this was on way to do it.