# Handler "dotless" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, dotless

When I want to use dotless (http://www.dotlesscss.org/) I have a problem:

When I try to request file `http://localhost/static/css/StyleLess.less` I am receiving a HTTP error:

> Handler "dotless" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list.

- MVC 4
- asp.net 4.0
- IIS 7 classic mode

However, if application pool is set as "Integrated" I don't have problem.

I've tried to use, among others

- [How to get rid of this error Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659862/how-to-get-rid-of-this-error-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-m)
- [How to fix: Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip)

with no success

Answer (score 1):

Change of App Pool mode from `Classic` to `Integrated` helped me and solved that problem.