# web.config causing problems with iis

Tags: iis, web-config, phalanger

Up until now I have only worked with this web.config within Visual Studio.  However I am now trying to publish my website to IIS and there are errors associated with my web.config.  It seems that it crashes on configuration data for a module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
  <phpNet>
    <classLibrary>
      <add assembly="php_mcrypt.mng, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ef6ed87c53048a3" section="mcrypt" />
      <add assembly="php_curl.mng, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ef6ed87c53048a3" section="curl" />
    </classLibrary>
    <scriptLibrary/>
  </phpNet>

</configuration>
```

error:

[image]

This screenshot is when trying to double click on any "Feature" within the "Feature View" of IIS.  However if i just hit the website via a browser the error is the same:

> The configuration section 'phpNet' cannot be read because it is
>   missing a section declaration

phpNet is for [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/), and the extension should be installed but I do not know how to check that.  Like I said though, this web.config and phalanger worked fine within visual studio so Im not sure whats wrong.  Especially since the installer did install the samples in iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this posting http://crdevelopment.net/2012/06/12/fixing-iis-error-the-configuration-section-system-web-extensions-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-declaration/

which led me to check the application pools. 
[image]

At which point I noticed there where multiples.  I selected the phalangerAppPool and that got rid of my error, but brought about a new one.

> Handler “PageHandlerFactory-Integrated” has a bad module
>   “ManagedPipelineHandler” in its module list

However that error was alot easier to resolve ([fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10541165/530933))

Answer (score 1):

You are missing configuration section definition

```
<configSections>
<section name="phpNet" type="PHP.Core.ConfigurationSectionHandler, PhpNetCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a8e8c4c76728c71" />
```

Without this, .NET does not know the 'phpNet' configuration section.

Also this means, you don't have Phalanger installed using setup.exe. Here are some information about using Phalanger without proper installation (important is the part about configuration) http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2011/installation-free-phalanger-web

Comment: What about the answer I posted?  Because once i started using the "PhalangerAppPool" things worked.

Comment: I also ended up moving these statments to the master.config in the .net/frameworks/v4/config directory