# Access Web Service via Local Area Network

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

My problem is that I tried changing the localhost to `ip address`/`computer name` and still cannot access. My web service  link goes like this `http://localhost:1228/TryService.asmx?op=HelloWorld`.

How can I make it accessible thru the local area network?

Thanks for the reply

Current Code:

I haven't touched in webconfig

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for EDCService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class EDCService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

app MOVE TO IIS UPDATE:

ERROR

```
 HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

Comment: are you working behind a proxy server

Comment: no, Im just working on a pc, in visual studio

Comment: firewall is turned off

Comment: @Damith, in a PC. pc is networked to others pc's

Comment: @SHINHAN: Please move the app to IIS and then post the update here. Your development server cannot be shared across the network.

Comment: @saravanan, APP MOVED TO THE IIS UPDATE

Comment: Please refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip.
It has resolution for your issue.

Comment: doesn't seem to be network related, since you're getting a response from the server. the error seems to point to a configuration error.