# Classic ASP setup on IIS 8.5 error, HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, internal-server-error

I have a classic asp page very simple, and I want to run is on a windows server 2012, iis 8.5, 
I setup the site, and when I run it http://localhost/default.asp
I got an error:

HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "asp" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Comment: I do not know the answer, but A) what have you tried? and B) did searching turn up anything useful? A very brief google turned up a few threads on S.O. that might be relevant, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip

Comment: I placed the classic asp page under wwwroot; I have setup a default.asp as default start page (which only show a simple text) for Defaultwebsite; I gave permission to IIS_User, IUser; and when I run it as localhost/default.asp it fails, and showed: Handler "asp" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list